# R combining a df with a factor

Tags: r, dataframe

I am pretty new to R and am trying to combine a df with a factor.

My df is a dataframe of 300 by 2, and the factor is created from sampling the 300 rows and assigning them to 1,2,3. I would like to know how to combine my factor to the df. Basically, I want the factor variable shown as a column of my df.

```
library(mvtnorm)
cv <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), ncol = 2)
df <- rmvnorm(300, mean = c(3, 3), sigma = cv)
factors <- factor(sample(c(1, 2, 3), 300, replace = TRUE))
```

I tried `merge(db, factors)` but it did not work. I also tried to turn the factors variable into a df, but still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Sorry, I added the code, but am not really sure how to show the expected output

Comment: You don't necessarily need to convert data to dataframe, you can keep it a matrix and `cbind`. `cbind(df, factors)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `df` is a matrix, not a data frame.  Make it a data frame, then you can add `factors` as a column easily:

```r
df <- rmvnorm(300, mean = c(3, 3), sigma = cv)
class(df) # "matrix"

df <- data.frame(df)
class(df) # "data.frame"

df$factors <- factors
```

Comment: you are totally right... I think I just named it df and forgot that it is still a matrix... thanks a lot!